# accessing a struct variable from a void pointer from a node pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void-pointers

I am very new to C (am trying to code in C89 specifically), and I'm trying to better understand how void pointers and structs work.
I was messing around and was able to access a variable inside a struct from just a plain void pointer variable. But when I put that void pointer variable inside a struct, I get an error.

The only similar problems I've found online are people accessing a struct from a void pointer, but not a from a void pointer that is inside of a struct itself.

When I run this code, I get an error;
"error: expected identifier before '(' token"
[image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvsSg.png)

Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
struct box
{
    int val;
};

struct Node
{
     void * data;
};

int main()
{
struct Node * node;
node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

node->data = (struct box *)malloc(sizeof(struct box));

(*node).(*(struct box *)data).val = 5;

printf("val:   %d \n", (*node).(*(struct box *)data).val);

free(node->data);
free(node;)

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right operand of the `.` operator cannot be some general expression. It must be a member name of the union or structure being accessed.

After `(*node).`, you can write `data` to access the value of the `data` member. Then `(*node).data` is an expression you can operate on further. You can convert that expression to `struct box *` and dereference it with `* (struct box *) (*node).data`, and then you can access the `val` member of that structure with `(* (struct box *) (*node).data).val`.

And of course the `->` operator allows you to replace combinations of `*` and `.` with the simpler `->`, giving `((struct box *) node->data)->val`.

Comment: so essentially you have to typecast the dereferencing of node to be a struct pointer, before you actually dereference it ?